Remove two plus sign from phone number field in SQL
I want to remove two plus(+) sign from phone number field and add just one plus sign.
For eg: The phone number can be in any of these formats:
(+) (+911) 24234324324324
++091787534 5303
(++91) 9711931220`

Desired Output:
(+911) 24234324324324
+091787534 5303
(+91) 9711931220`

Below is the query that I am using
**replace((TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM (REGEXP_REPLACE(channel_value, '[\]\\[!@#$%.&*~^_{}:;<>/\\|()+-]', '')))),' ' ,'')**

Waiting for your suggestions.
Thank you.

Mysql is not SQL server, please correct your tags

Can't you replace )( (possibly with spaces in between) by nothing, then replace ++ with +?

What cases are possible that you need to replace? I think it will likely be easier to split this task in the different use cases and run one update command for each case. Trying to do that all in one could be risky and do more than intended.

replace this pattern: (\()?(?:\+\)?\s?\(?){2}
with: $1+
fiddle
